# How to configure MySQL as Tomcat 9 realm for user credentials

Tags: mysql, tomcat, realm, jdbcrealm

I am trying to connect a MySQL user table as a realm to my Tomcat 9. The user and roles are managed in 2 tables, as you can see in the realm configuration below. The passwords are MD5-hashed and Base64-encoded.

Unfortunately, I do not get it running properly.

**REALM CONFIGURATION:**

```
<!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords via a brute-force attack -->

<!--<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"> -->
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->

        <!--<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>-->

                <!-- Custom realm for user database -->
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                        debug="99"
                        driverName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver.example.com:3306/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;autoReconnect=true"
                        connectionName="MYSQLDB"
                        connectionPassword="MYSQL_PASSWORD"
                        userTable="myuser" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
                        userRoleTable="myuser_roles" roleNameCol="role"/>
                        <CredentialHandler
                        className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
                        algorithm="{MD5}encodedCredential"
                        iterations="1"
                        saltLength="0"/>
<!-- </Realm> -->
```

**WORKS:**

When I save a password as plain text in the database and remove the CrendetialHandler from the configuration, it works. So, the database connection/configuration seems to be correct.

**DOES NOT WORK:**

As soon as the the password is saved hashed and encoded, it does not work anymore. I tried several CredentialHandler settings, but always getting an error, for example the latest:

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement No rules found matching [Server/Service/Engine/CredentialHandler]
```

or

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.setCredentialHandler A CredentialHandler was set on an instance of the CombinedRealm (or a sub-class of CombinedRealm). CombinedRealm doesn't use a configured CredentialHandler. Is this a configuration error?
```

As you can see, I also tried to comment out the existing logout realm or put the CrendentialHandler into it. Nevertheless, it does not work yet.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running against a MySQL server on the same machine or different machine?  I can make your exact scenario work fine on same machine - but am also troubleshooting when the MySQL server is on a different machine.  When the MySQL server is "localhost", "127.0.0.1", or the DNS name or IP address of the same machine - it all works great.  My configuration worked perfectly in Tomcat8.  Tomcat 9 has deprecated JDBCRelam - and discouraging "Production" use - so this may be related.  I may post the issue I face on another thread.  If I do I will cross post that thread here.

Comment: The MySQL is running on a different machine, but the connection works, becuase plaintext passwords are OK. Nevertheless, I did not know yet, that the JDBC Realm is deprecated. So, I completely changed my configuration to a DataSourceRealm. After some tests, this works fine for plaintext and MD5, but same issues, when the password is MD5 base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "CredentialHandler" is sitting outside of your "Realm"  That may be one of your issues (you close the Realm at the end of the "roleNameCol").  I also list the algorithm in my code as simply "MD5" vs what you show.  That may also be a problem.

I would fix it such as below (I explicitly close the "CredentialHandler" and the "Realm" to be more clear):

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
    debug="99"
    driverName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://mysqlserver.example.com:3306/database?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;autoReconnect=true"
    connectionName="MYSQLDB"
    connectionPassword="MYSQL_PASSWORD"
    userTable="myuser" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
    userRoleTable="myuser_roles" roleNameCol="role">
    <CredentialHandler
        className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MessageDigestCredentialHandler"
            algorithm="{MD5}encodedCredential"
            iterations="1"
            saltLength="0">
    </CredentialHandler>
</Realm>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, I switched to a DataSourceRealm now, since the JDBC realm is deprecated. It works with plaintext and MD5, but not with MD5 encoded as Base64.

I tried the MessageDigestCredentialHandler with algorithm="MD5", which works, when the password is MD5. 

Afterwards I tried algorithm="{MD5}encodedCredential", but it does not work.

I also tried algorithm="MD5" and added a encoding="Base64" which does not work, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you consider marking the above answer as correct since it solved the two error messages that were occurring in the example?  If you post a new example with your DataSourceRealm and reference it here, I can look at that. I have mine working on DataSourceRealm now as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will start a new thread as soon as I have enough time to investigate the new problem with the DataSourceRealm.